# merge files with macro from server

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have macros to merge .csv files.
It is working when I am merging files from folder witch placed at desktop, 
But when I am trying to merge files that are placed on a server then macro does not work.

Any ides Why?
I can show that part of selecting folder with .csv files:

```
    Dim fileCount As Long

' Open the file dialog
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Add "CSV files", "*.csv"
    .Show

    For fileCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        Debug.Print .SelectedItems(fileCount)
    Next fileCount

End With
```

And I am creating the .txt file to collect all data

```
'Create the bat file
        Open BatFileName For Output As #1
        Print #1, "Copy " & Chr(34) & foldername & "*.csv" _
                & Chr(34) & " " & TXTFileName
        Close #1

        'Run the Bat file to collect all data from the CSV files into a TXT file
        ShellAndWait BatFileName, 0
        If Dir(TXTFileName) = "" Then
            MsgBox "There are no csv files in this folder"
            Kill BatFileName
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

What is the diference between file on desktop and file on server?

**I get message when i am merging files from server: there are no csv files in this folder
But i am sure that there are .csv files.**

Thanks

Comment: "*macro do not work*" Is not a useful error description is you can easily imagine. Please [edit] your question and explain (1) what should your code do and (2) what does it instead. (3) Do you get any error messages if so in which line and what is the message. (4) how does the server path look like? UNC path or mapped drive? (5) are the server files exactly the same files as the local ones?

Comment: What is the value of `TXTFileName` in case of not working? Obviously this must be no valid directory otherwise the error message would not appear. And how is it initialized? Please also show the relevant code parts in your question. Debug step-by-step (F8) or use `Debug.Print TXTFileName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what 'does not work' actually means.  I'm guessing you don't have Excel installed, but you should know whether that's true or not before posting here, so we can probably rule out that option.  More likely, it's not working in a web-based environment.  VBA doesn't work in any web environment, like a Web Server, Website, SharePoint, etc.  In addition,     Make sure you are granting System Access to your macros in the server through QEMC (System, Setup, QlikView Servers, expand and click, Seucrity tab in the right pane "Allow unsafe macro execution on server" and "Allow macro execution on server" ticked) and in the Macro editor, (Ctrl + M, bottom left drop downs).  Finally, if they are creating some filesystem object (such an excel file) make sure you are using the IE Plugin.